# mySQL connection and loading images to Qt

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt

I want to connect to a mySQL database with python, then query a number corresponding to an image, and load this image in Qt.  From what I found online, it is suggested not to use mysql database to store the image, but instead store a file location on the server.  If this is the case, can I load the image (do i have to download it?) into qt using mysql or do i have to open another connection with ftp, download the image to a folder, and then load it with qt?  If there are any resources on this type of workflow I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download the file using `FTP` (or the like) to load it into `Qt`.

Assuming the database stores the correct file path to the image, you can just use the same functionality once you get the file path, i.e. you anyway only need the file path to load the image into `Qt`. There is nothing special you would do by downloading the image itself.

If the database is on a remote server, a possible approach is to use the `JDBC` API to access the database, get the image as a binary file and then serialize it, which can be transferred over the network.

Comment: to be clear, the mysql server is not on a local machine, im connecting through the IP to a remote host, in which the file is located on that remote server... how does qt load an image on a remote server through a mysql connection?

Comment: If it's on a remote server, you would need to employ a suitable mechanism to cache it to local and load the image into `Qt`.

Comment: so which options are there,  i mention in my post ftp, since that is the only one im aware of, but is there a simple method for loading these images other than setting up sftp clients in order to transfer image files

Comment: That boils down to basically getting a file stored in the database. You can use the `jdbc` api in your case to access the database server and then get the image as a sequence of bytes - that's just one approach among many.